# Runtime Error after using index_add function in pytorch

Tags: python, pytorch, runtime-error

I have a problem I cannot manage to solve... I read the Pytorch documentation to get rid of this but my code looks fine to me, but an error occurs.

```
        indices = ...
        X = ...
        Y = ...

        print(torch.min(indices)) # tensor(0, device='cuda:0')
        print(torch.max(indices)) # tensor(30, device='cuda:0')
        print(indices.dtype) # torch.int64
        print(indices.shape) # torch.Size([498])

        print(X.shape) # torch.Size([498, 2048])
        print(X.dtype) # torch.float32

        print(Y.shape) # torch.Size([31, 2048])
        print(Y.dtype) # torch.float32

        Y = Y.index_add(0, indices, X)
```

The call of index_add results in:

```
RuntimeError: number of dims don't match in permute
```

What am I doing wrong? Thank you in advance.

EDIT:
From the documentation:

> The dim-th dimension of tensor must have the same size as the length of
> index (which must be a vector), and all other dimensions must match
> self, or an error will be raised.

In this case `dim=0 tensor=X self=Y` and it follows that `X.shape[0]` should be equal to `len(indices)` and that `X.shape[1]` should be equal `Y.shape[1]`, that is the case... might it be a pytorch bug?

EDIT2:
The error occurs just for specific values of tensors and using:

```
torch.use_deterministic_algorithms(True)
torch.manual_seed(1234)
```

So it should be a pytorch bug.

Comment: Can you provide a fully reproducible code for the bug ? With seeds and specific tensors.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably trying to do

```
X = X.index_add(0, indices, Y)
```

you swapped `X` and `Y`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but no, I want to add X to Y using the indices, I refer to the example in https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.Tensor.index_add_.html

Comment: From my understanding I need to have one index for each row of X that will be used to add that row to the row of Y specified by the index. X has 498 rows and I have 498 indices between 0 and 30 (in fact Y has 31 rows). Am I wrong? In the example I referred seem it works in this way

Comment: Strange, I just simulated your stuff with a minimal example, and it works. https://pastebin.com/4Unt5mka (this code works without any error). See if I reproduced correctly.

Comment: Yes you did it correctly and substituting in my code my tensors with random ones it works aswell... with the values of my particular tensors it raises the exception